# Android - Setting an ImageView content from another class

Tags: android, class, imageview

Here's the thing:
I have two classes: Main and control.java 
the Main class is an Activity class where I build my app and the control class I just use for variables controls that I must access from other classes.

The problem is: In class Main I got 2 methods, and I have an ImageView in each of them, I need to set the image view resource of the second method on a click listener of the first one. Like this:

```
public void first() {
    final ImageView first = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myview);
    first.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myimage);
}

public void second() {
    final ImageView second = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myview2);
    //And then, I want something like this: first.setBackgroundResource(first);
}
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I admit to being a bit confused by your question but I think below is at least the start of what you're looking for

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    control.setImageView((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myview));
    second = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myview2);
}
public void first() {

    control.getImageView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myimage);
}

public void second() {
    second.setBackgroundDrawable(control.getImageView().getDrawable());
}

ImageView second;
```

Comment: Let me try this:
on the class "control" I have an ImageView, and I want to set it content with a button listener on method "first" from class "Main"

Then, on the "second" method I want to get the content from the ImageView of the class "control", like this:

imageview2.setBackgroundResource(control.image);

Comment: @RaphaelPedrini you mean like this? (made an edit) or am I missing something

Comment: thats it, Raymond...but this code didn't work for me :/ ...but that's kinda what I want to do.

Comment: on class "control" I got a static ImageView = controlImg;  and on class "Main" I want to set a drawable for controlImg and then assign the method "second" imageview with the drawable of the class "control"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do something like:

```
public void second() {
    final ImageView second = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myview2);
    final ImageView first = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myview);
    first.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myimage);
}
```

Otherwise, you'd have to use a private/public class variable and define it outside the method.